# MySQL, Verify if 2 records has common field

Tags: mysql, fetch

```
id     |     sample     |     field_a     |     field_b
-------------------------------------------------------
1      |     a     |     1     |      NULL
2      |     a     |   NULL    |       1
3      |     b     |     1     |      NULL
```

I want to fetch if there is records which has common `sample` value, but field_a must be '1' and field_b must be '1'.

Attention: field_a and field_b couldn't defined at the same records (field_a or field_b in each record).

With the example that I showed, I should get back TRUE, because I've got 2 record with 'a' value and field_a = 1 and field_b = 1.

How can I do this?

Comment: So the only value you want returned is TRUE or FALSE, no matter which or how many values that fulfil the condition?

Comment: Yes. Just verified if there is a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some MySQL'isms, you can use a simple `GROUP BY`;

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM mytable
  GROUP BY sample
  HAVING MAX(field_a=1) AND MAX(field_b=1)
) THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END `match`;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9bf758/3).

Comment: This will return true, even if the matches are in the same row, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5993/2

Comment: @VMai, It's okay, because I made not being able to do so. In the bottom line, works WELL!

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with a self join:

```
SELECT 
    e.id, 
    e.sample, 
    e.field_a, 
    e1.field_b 
FROM 
    example e
INNER JOIN 
    example e1
ON 
    e.id < e1.id
WHERE 
    e.field_a = 1 AND e1.field_b = 1;
```

The condition

```
e.id < e1.id
```

takes care that every combination will be evaluated only once and that they are in different rows.

**[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/add10/5)**

To get only True (1) or False modify this query to

```
  SELECT 
     (COUNT(e.id)>0) as result
  FROM 
     example e
  INNER JOIN 
     example e1
  ON e.id < e1.id
  WHERE e.field_a = 1 AND e1.field_b = 1
  GROUP BY e.id;
```

**[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/add10/7)**

Answer (score 0):

Create a view (or subquery) that groups the data like this:

```
select sample, MAX(field_a) as field_a, MAX(field_b) as field_b, count(sample) as entries from test
group by sample
```

Now your results will look like this:

> sample    field_a field_b entries
>
> a 1   1   2
>
> b 1   NULL    1

From here you can select all samples where field_a and field_b are 1.

Using a view makes it easier to test and review, but you can also just select from these query results if you prefer.